# Narrowing conversion from byte to char Java

Tags: java

I read that although type byte occupies 8 bits of memory, and type char occupies 16 bits of memory, the conversion from byte to char is considered narrowing because byte is signed, while char is unsigned. I think this means that when we convert a type byte with a negative value to char, we lose the negative and so that is our loss of information and so the conversion is narrowing.

I am trying to test this in a Java program.

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    byte num = -1;
    char test = (char)num;
    System.out.println(test);
  }
}
```

I expected that printing test would output:

```
1
```

This would be -1 without the negative sign because char is unsigned. This in fact outputs:

```
?
```

Is there something wrong with my program or with my idea about converting byte to char?

Comment: Just use a debugger and look what `test` "contains", then you'll understand.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4.

Comment: (the duplicate question also contains the underflow during this conversion which also happens here)

Comment: In binary: byte:         11111111 (-1)
char: 1111111111111111 (65535)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how signs or `char` works.

1. Bear in mind that `System.out.println` will show you the *UTF-8 character* (which is the same as ascii for the first 8 bits of values) for a `char`. So `System.out.println((char)71);` will print "G". So when you expect to see "1" to be printed, what you're saying is that you expect `(char)-1 == 41`. If you want the numeric value, you should cast it to `int` before printing.
2. `System.out.println` will [substitute a question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19038353/860453) for unprintable characters.
3. `byte` to `char` first is converted to an `int`. The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4) (linked by Sotirios Delimanolis) says;

> First, the byte is converted to an int via widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2), and then the resulting int is converted to a char by narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3).

Where

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T